# Create URL dynamically according to models in Django

Tags: django, url

I'm trying to write URL paths according to data inside Django database (models). Below, my URL.py file:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path    
from .models import Seller

sellers = Seller.objects.all
    
app_name = 'root'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),

    for seller in sellers:
      path(seller.name, views.seller, name='sellers'),    
]
```

I know the 'for-loop' inside the urlpatterns list is completely wrong.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating URLs, you don't have to create a specific url for every object.

In urls.py:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path    
    
app_name = 'root'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<str:seller_name>/', views.your_function, name="seller_page")

]
```

In views.py

```
from .models import Seller

def your_function(request, seller_name):

    # Do something with the object
```

Happy coding!